# Stream apps not using the buildpack provided in SCDF server environment variable (SCDF ver 2.1.2)

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

Recently, I upgraded from SCDF 1.7.3 to SCDF 2.1.2 for cloud foundry. Also, I am using skipper (I have to with 2.x). There are two main problems I am facing:-

1. Buildpack given as a property in the SCDF server environment is not being used to deploy stream applications. Following is the env key that I am using:-
   SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_STREAM_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[xxx]_DEPLOYMENT_BUILDPACK. This has no effect at all.
2. Even though I set SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_STREAM_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[xxx]_DEPLOYMENT_ENABLE_RANDOM_APP_NAME_PREFIX to false skipper still generates random prefix for these applications.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any advice will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no stream platform properties with the prefix `SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_STREAM_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY` in Spring Cloud Data Flow as the stream deployments are managed by Spring Cloud Skipper. Hence, you need to use the Skipper properties for stream deployment-related configurations.

The correct properties to use in this case are:

SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[xxx]_DEPLOYMENT_ENABLERANDOMAPPNAMEPREFIX: false
SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[xxx]_DEPLOYMENT_BUILDPACK:

Comment: Thank You. The above answer worked. I am facing one last issue wherein, the version numbers get appended in the route. So every time I deploy a stream the app version number increments and the route changes. case I need to have static routes for some of the apps. I was able to achieve it using deployer.<app>.cloudfoundry.host. But is this the only way? Do we have any other way by passing properties in Skipper or scdf server to not include version number. I tried to add SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[xxx]_DEPLOYMENT_DELETE_ROUTES to false. But this did not work

Comment: I think the correct property is `SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[xxx]_DEPLOYMENT_DELETEROUTES`. Can you try and see if that works for you?

Comment: Even with this, I presume we will still have an app_v# version number suffixed. Is it possible to tell the skipper to not include version numbers in the route at all?